# Double integral over semi-circular domain

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $D=\{(x,y)\in R^2 : x^2+y^2\le1,\space x\ge0\}$, then 
\begin{equation}
\int \int_D \frac{tan(y)}{1+x^2+y^2}dydx\ge1
\end{equation}

I do not know how to approach the problem.  I have tried explicitly integrating the function but I can not see an obvious way to do it.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean to have the *inverse* tangent in the numerator?

Comment: Thats what I thought too! Apparently the problem is given this way.  With the inverse tan it would really simplify.

Comment: Well then my gut tells me the problem has a typo. If I were the person assigning this problem, I would write in parentheses at the bottom that I really do mean $\tan{y}$ and not $\arctan{y}$.

Comment: maybe its possible to calculate the integral using $arctan(y)$ instead of $tan(y)$.  Then, since $arctan$ is always less than $tan$ on the interval of [0,1] then maybe this can prove the above statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use polar coordinates : 
$$\int \int_D \frac{\tan(y)}{1+x^2+y^2}dydx=\int_0^{\pi} \int_0^1 \frac{r\tan(r\sin(\theta))}{1+r^2}drd\theta=\int_0^1 \int_0^{\pi} \frac{r\tan(r\sin(\theta))}{1+r^2}d\theta dr=\int_0^1 \frac{r}{1+r^2}\int_0^{\pi} \tan(r\sin(\theta))d\theta dr$$
But $r\sin(\theta)\le r$ for $\theta \in [0,\pi]$.
$$\int \int_D \frac{\tan(y)}{1+x^2+y^2}dydx\le \int_0^1 \frac{r}{1+r^2}\int_0^{\pi} \tan(r)d\theta dr=\int_0^1 \frac{\pi r\tan(r)}{1+r^2} dr$$
But $\tan(r)\le r$ for $r \in [0,1]$.
$$\int \int_D \frac{\tan(y)}{1+x^2+y^2}dydx\le \pi\int_0^1 \frac{ r^2}{1+r^2} dr=\pi[r-\arctan(r)]_0^1=\pi-\frac{\pi^2}{4}<1$$

So the result seems wrong.

Comment: This makes sense! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Since your function $f$ is odd in $y$ and the domain is symmetric in $y$, your integral equals $0$, which is indeed less than $1$. (From the comments it is mentioned that perhaps $\tan y$ should be $\arctan y$. But the same conclusion holds also in that case.)